# How can I calculate the sum of a boolean column in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a column with boolean values and would like to use the 'sum' function to calculate a total. This column is used for getting a vote count similar to Stack Overflow or reddit.

Here's my code

```
votes = Vote.all
total = votes.sum(:direction)
puts' ....................' + total.to_s
```

And here's my error...

```
undefined method `+' for #<Vote:0x000000047c9170>
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: `Vote.sum(:direction)` http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-sum It executes a db query, which you can't do because you already call `.all` on your relation. Otherwise you can do: `votes.map(&:direction).reduce(:+)` or `votes.sum(&:direction)`

Comment: Is this the best practice, or should I be using a scope?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A sum of a boolean value? I'd just count the values with either `direction=false` or `direction=true`

```
total_down = Vote.where(direction: false).count #down vote
total_up = Vote.where(direction: true).count #up vote
puts "....... #{total_up} .... #{total_down}"
```